# PySpark MongoDB data source not found error when writing data to MongoDB using Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write data to MongoDB using PySpark in a Docker container. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: mongodb. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:73
```

I'm using the following Docker setup:

Dockerfile:

```
# Use Python 3.9 as the base image
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN conda install --yes --file requirements.txt

COPY ./src ./src

COPY ./csv_data ./csv_data

USER root
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: beamx
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    command: jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser --NotebookApp.password='sha256:1b88391210c8:20b66daeff713a802e6bd10185ffce8cf9ddb6b9c5934a4fabab218959e8612a'
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

requirements.txt:

```
pymongo
pyspark[mongodb]
```

And here's my code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

csv_file_path = "../csv_data/2023-07-14.csv"
# MongoDB connection details
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING = 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'mycollection'
conn_str = MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING + '/' + DATABASE_NAME + "." + COLLECTION_NAME

conn_str

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("csvTOmongo") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase.mycollection") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase.mycollection") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(csv_file_path)

df.write.format("mongodb").mode("append").save()
```

I've already installed the necessary dependencies (`pymongo` and `pyspark[mongodb]`) and configured the MongoDB connection in the SparkSession. However, I keep getting the `org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: mongodb` error when trying to save the data to MongoDB.

What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?  Thank you!

Comment: You need to load the jar files required by mongodb into your sparkcontext as well. You can download the following jar files from Maven (for the appropriate Spark and Scala version): mongo-spark-connector, mongodb-driver-sync, mongodb-driver-core, bson. Then set `spark.jars` to the paths containing the 4 files in your SparkConfig as well.

Comment: I'm not very good at Java. How can I do this in Docker? @ksgj1